# How do i count occurences that were joined SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am joining two tables:

```
DECLARE @Temp TABLE (
id INT)

INSERT INTO @Temp
VALUES (5)
,(2)
,(3)

DECLARE @Temp2 TABLE (
member_id INT)

INSERT INTO @Temp2
VALUES (5)
,(1)
,(3)
```

How do i count the number of rows that can be LEFT joined and the ones that can't.
In this example: 5 & 3 from @Temp can be joined to @Temp2 and only 2 from @Temp can't be joined.
I would like my output to show the following:

```
+--------+------------+
| Joined | Not_Joined |
+--------+------------+
|      2 |          1 |
+--------+------------+
```

Comment: You would use COUNT or conditional SUM.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this in a single query using COUNT and SUM. This should produce the results you are looking for.

```
DECLARE @Temp TABLE (
id INT)

INSERT INTO @Temp
VALUES (5)
,(2)
,(3)

DECLARE @Temp2 TABLE (
member_id INT)

INSERT INTO @Temp2
VALUES (5)
,(1)
,(3)

select Joined = count(t2.Member_id)
    , NotJoined = sum(case when t2.Member_id is null then 1 end)
from @Temp t
left join @Temp2 t2 on t2.member_id = t.id
```

Comment: YUP thats exactly what i was looking for thank you!!
why is my question downgraded?

Comment: Not my downvote but my guess is because you didn't show that you tried something. Seems pretty harsh to me. I thought your question was fine. And great job posting data and desired results!!

Comment: thanks @SeanLange, i have the article and sources you posted on my last post in my bookmarks ;)

Answer (score 0):

The count from @Temp that EXISTS in @Temp2:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM @TEMP WHERE ID IN(SELECT MEMBER_ID FROM @TEMP2)
```

The count from @Temp2 not in @Temp:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM @TEMP2 WHERE MEMBER_ID NOT IN(ID FROM @TEMP)
```

Now to create a single result set, there are many ways but here is a simple one:

```
SELECT 
    (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM @TEMP2 WHERE MEMBER_ID IN(ID FROM @TEMP)) AS [Joined],
    (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM @TEMP WHERE ID NOT IN(SELECT MEMBER_ID FROM @TEMP2)) AS [NotJoined]
```

@Sean Lange's answer is more specific to the JOIN question, my answer simply counts what exists in the lists.

Comment: thats equally good as the answer above. nice to know alternatives. thank you

Answer (score -1):

```
Select count(*) as 'NOT Joined ',
 (Select t1.count(*) from table1 
 t1)-count(*) as 'Joined' 
 from table1 where id NOT IN (Select member_id from table2);
```

---

> Its basically how a left join works that is Common values of both the
>   tables plus the value of table 1 which doesnt exists in table 2.

Comment: The OP put in the effort to provide sample data and a nice consumable format. This as posted has several syntax errors. The OP deserves better.

Comment: Because your code doesn't work as posted. If you fix the code so it works it would be considerably better.

Comment: @Sean Lange Can you please check it now

Comment: All you did was format it. There are still syntax errors. And since the OP posted such nice consumable data it really should work with what they posted.